# How do I return multi valued attributes using JDBC?

Tags: java, single-sign-on, cas, jasig

The Jasig CAS API exposes 2 implementations of IPersonAttributeDao for JDBC:

```
- SingleRowJdbcPersonAttributeDao
- MultiRowJdbcPersonAttributeDao
```

However both of these Dao implementations seem to work with attributes with single values.

Does Jasig CAS have a JDBC implementation that supports multi valued attributes like their LDAP implementation?